# Setting up the Conceptnet with apache solr

Tags: python, solr, artificial-intelligence, reasoning

I am trying to use common sense reasoning. In which I came across this cool thing called Conceptnet http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/. There is a also search page for searching different concepts. Here is the [**Search Page(link)**](http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/web/c/en/born) for that. 
I wanted to use it through python. I tried this [**Calling conceptnet through api calls(link)**](https://github.com/israkir/conceptnet5-client). But
I want to set it up onto my machine locally with python and ubuntu. They have given the method for setting it up [**Setting concpetnet locally(link)**](https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5/wiki/Running-your-own-copy). In this they are using sqlite for indexing purpose. But I wanted to know how can I use Apache solr for the same purpose. I am new to apache solr, so will it be possible using apache solr instead od sqlite and also will that change the following method, which is being used into the current thing for calling conceptnet through python.

```
>>> from conceptnet5.query import lookup
>>> for assertion in lookup('/c/en/example'):
...     print(assertion)
```

Help is appreciated. Thankz :)

Answer (score 2):

This paragraph:

> Using SQLite is a tradeoff; we can't write to it as quickly as we did
>   to Solr, but on the other hand, once the data is in it, it's easier to
>   run and uses less RAM than Solr.

would seem to indicate that they used to use Solr and switched to SQLite. So it might not be easily possible anymore to use Solr. Your best bet would be to send them an email and ask.

Answer (score 1):

Consider running ConceptNet via a stand-alone docker VM image.  You can use the web or api version or the 'full' deployment gives you full access to the tech stack:

https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5/wiki/Docker